# Play / Record .DSS or .DS2 files

Tags: java, android, audio, android-audiomanager

I have a project running which should allow to play and eventually also record .DSS ("Digital Speech Standard") and .DS2 ("Digital Speech Standard Pro") audio files.  However, I can't seem to find anything about it. Is there any way possible to achieve this or any library possibly there to get it up and running?

I am atm using the android built-in android.media.MediaPlayer, if this is useful anyhow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find anything? Is there any OpenSource implementation?

Comment: No. It's a proprietary file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked this out too. DS2 and DSS is proprietarily owned by  Olympus, Philips and Grundig. SO the documentation is pretty hush hush. That's why your having such a hard time finding any information on it. It's dumb, I know. I wish it was more open source but there is hope. A month ago I saw an iPhone app that used DS2 and DSS files to some extent and they were not a company affiliated with Olympus, Philips, or Grundig. So it may be out there somewhere. For now you may have to work around this issue. Can I ask what you plan to do with the .dss and .ds2 files so I can offer suggestions on possible work-arounds.

[Wiki on Digital Speech Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Speech_Standard)