# Playing Audio Files, DS2 and DSS, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

From a post at [Play / Record .DSS or .DS2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259262/play-record-dss-or-ds2-files) I understand that there isn't much information online and was wondering if someone could provide me with some guidance and a workaround.

I want to be able to play DS2 and DSS files in the browser.

At the present moment I think that I have 2 possible ways around it:

a) Find solution for a question above

b) See if it is possible to convert DS2 / DSS files into something like MP3

Answer (score 0):

DSS is a proprietary format, so it's not supported by the HTML5 audio controls. I'm looking for converters but it seems that you need to register for Olympus' SDK.

Alternatively, some people are mentioning NCH Switch which does support the conversion: http://www.nch.com.au/switch/

Note: I haven't used this, and it's not free.